# How to identify failed transactions on Solana

Tags: transactions, getsignaturesforaddress, failed

I am trying to fetch only the successful transactions on Solana. For this I use 2 functions under different scenarios, to fetch signatures and txns:

```
1. connection.getParsedTransaction(tx_signature, {commitment:'confirmed'});
2. connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address, {before: before_tx_signature, limit: tx_num || 10}, 'confirmed');
```

Even after using commitment as both `finalized` and `confirmed`, I still get failed transactions from the Solana blockchain.
Is there a way to fetch only signatures and transactions that have been successful in Solana and not get the data for failed ones?

Answer (score 1):

A transaction gets `confirmed` and `finalized`, whether it's a success or a failure, since the whole network needs to run it to be sure that it fails.

There is no way to only filter by success or failure at the JSON RPC level, so you have to fetch all transactions and filter out the failed transactions.